# Converting a callback object into an asynchronous Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have an interface supplied to me that looks like this:

```
public interface IFuture<T>
{
    FutureState state { get; }
    T value { get; }
    Exception error { get; }
    IFuture<T> OnItem(FutureValueCallback<T> callback);
    IFuture<T> OnSuccess(FutureValueCallback<T> callback);
    IFuture<T> OnError(FutureErrorCallback callback);
    IFuture<T> OnComplete(FutureCallback<T> callback);
}
```

Here's the available states, as well as the decleration for the delegates:

```
public enum FutureState
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The future hasn't begun to resolve a value.
    /// </summary>
    Pending,

    /// <summary>
    /// The future is working on resolving a value.
    /// </summary>
    Processing,

    /// <summary>
    /// The future has a value ready.
    /// </summary>
    Success,

    /// <summary>
    /// The future failed to resolve a value.
    /// </summary>
    Error
}
public delegate void FutureCallback<T>(IFuture<T> future);

public delegate void FutureValueCallback<T>(T value);
public delegate void FutureErrorCallback(Exception error);
```

I would like to just be able to `await` this Future. I believe the best way forward would be to convert it to a `Task<T>`. But how would you go about doing this exactly? The signature would be this:

```
public static Task<T> ToAwaitable<T>(IFuture<T> future)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see possible values of `FutureState` (I'm assuming it's an `enum`). And the signatures of `FutureXCallback`s as well.

Comment: Added to the post, thanks.

Comment: What does the signature of `FutureCallback` mean? What's the `future` parameter it accepts? Can you show a use case of `OnCompleted`?

Comment: What's the difference between `OnItem` and `OnSuccess`? Can this "future" result in more than one item?

Comment: @StephenCleary  This interface comes from a library for Unity called 'Best HTTP'. `OnItem`: "Adds a new callback to invoke when an intermediate result is known."
`OnSuccess`: "Adds a new callback to invoke if the future value is retrieved successfully."
I think a more appropriate name for `OnItem` would be `OnIntermediateResult`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to wrap it into a `Task`, anything with a suitable `GetAwaiter()` method can be `await`ed.

```
public class AwaitableFuture<T>
{
    private readonly IFuture<T> _future;

    public AwaitableFuture(IFuture<T> future)
    {
        _future = future;
    }

    public FutureAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() => new FutureAwaiter<T>(_future);
}
```

`FutureAwaiter<T>` has to be an awaiter for type `T`. An object is an awaiter `T` if

- It implements `INotifyCompletion`;
- It has a `bool IsCompleted` get property;
- It has a `T GetResult()` method.

So an example implementation would be:

```
public class FutureAwaiter<T> : INotifyCompletion
{
    private readonly IFuture<T> _future;

    public bool IsCompleted => 
        _future.state == FutureState.Success || _future.state == FutureState.Error;

    public FutureAwaiter(IFuture<T> future)
    {
        _future = future;
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action action) => _future.OnComplete(_ => action());

    public T GetResult() => 
        _future.state == FutureState.Error ? _future.value : throw _future.error;
}
```

EDIT: Heeding Rafal's suggestions I've added error-throwing. He's also correct to suggest an extension method, so that you can `await` an `IFuture<T>` directly:

```
public static FutureAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter<T>(this IFuture<T> future) =>
    new FutureAwaiter<T>(future);
```

```
async Task PrintFuture<T>(IFuture<T> future)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Awaiting a future...");
    T result = await future;
    Console.WriteLine($"Future yielded {result}.");
}
```

Comment: Nice, did not know that. And you should throw on error in `GetResult` I presume.

You can make it an extension method `public static FutureAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter<T>(this IFuture<T> future) => new FutureAwaiter<T>(future);` and now you can await future directly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on implementation details of the future you can go like this:

`AsyncResult` is just a wrapper on Future that implements correct interface and attaches to callbacks.

```
internal class AsyncResult<T> : IAsyncResult
{
    private ManualResetEvent _manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public object AsyncState => null;

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle => _manualResetEvent;

    public bool CompletedSynchronously => false;

    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }

    public T Result { get; private set; }

    public Exception Error { get; private set; }

    public AsyncResult(IFuture<T> future)
    {
        future.OnSuccess(result =>
            {
                Result = result;
                IsCompleted = true;
                _manualResetEvent.Set();
            });

        future.OnError(() =>
        {
            Error = future.error;
            IsCompleted = true;
            _manualResetEvent.Set();
        });
    }
}
```

The method that converts `Future` into `Task` as you wanted:

```
public static class FutureExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> ToAsync<T>(this IFuture<T> future)
    {
        var asyncResult = new AsyncResult<T>(future);
        var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, x =>
        {
            var ar = (AsyncResult<T>)x;
            if (ar.Error != null)
            {
                throw new AggregateException("Task failed.", ar.Error);
            }

            return ar.Result;
        });

        return task;
    }
}
```

and sample usage:

```
internal static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var future = new Future(success: true);

        var result = await future.ToAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        var future2 = new Future(success: false);

        try
        {
            var result2 = await future2.ToAsync();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, the only difference was that `future.OnError(() =>` needs a parameter, like `future.OnError(error =>`. Thanks!